# java api similar to JTAPI?

Tags: telephony, java, tapi, jtapi

I am working on a project and I need to use this tow api; jtapi, gjtapi. The problem is

both gjtapi and jtapi project seem dead. Is there a new similar java api?

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I will try to create a generic java-api in order to control call , the goal of the api is that it could support any provider as well as asterisk or other

Answer (score 0):

JTapi is a specification that is implemented by vendors, as CISCO or AVAYA. In my experience, there is no an generic API for JTapi, because each provider customizes their own implementation according at their telephony platform.

If you want a "generic" JTapi you should review this link, that refer to an Asterisk JTapi:

http://asterisk-jtapi.sourceforge.net/